# Eagerly repopulate EhCache instead of waiting for a read

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

In my scenario, getting the fresh (non-cached) values is a very expensive operation so it is imperative pre-calculated cached values exist at all times instead of refreshing them on read, like EhCache seems to do.

For this it sounds reasonable to have a thread firing on TTL expiration repopulating the cache with fresh values, so no reads are ever waiting.

Is there a way to achieve this using Ehcache? Listening for OnElementExpired/Evicted events to repopulate the cache seems like a no-go (by the time I receive the event, a read would already be waiting).

I guess I could make the cache itself eternal and have my own scheduled task that repopulates, but then I get nothing from EhCache over dumb maps that I have now. Is this really how it is? Is there no way to have EhCache help me in this situation?

Comment: Huge wall of text crits me for 1000 ;) Please reformat it a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehcache provides a way of doing what you want with scheduled refresh.

You will need two things in order to make this work with Ehcache:

- Use a [cache loader](https://terracotta.org/generated/4.3.0/html/bmg-all/index.html#page/BigMemory_Go_Documentation_Set%2Fto-caload_cache_loaders.html%23) - that is move to a cache read-through pattern. This is required as otherwise Ehcache has no idea how to get to the data mapped to a key.
- Configure [scheduled refresh](https://terracotta.org/generated/4.3.0/html/bmm-all/#page/BigMemory_Max_Documentation_Set%2Fco-refresh_scheduled_refresh_ahead.html) - this works by launching a quartz scheduler instance.

Comment: This looks very promising. Thanks a lot! I'll read up some more and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RefreshAheadCache](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/refreshahead/RefreshAheadCache.html), provided by EHCache.

However, I cannot find any examples of its use and indicators that this is mature.

The comment of the class says:

> A cache decorator which implements read ahead refreshing. Read ahead occurs when a cache entry is accessed prior to its expiration, and triggers a reload of the value in the background.

This does not directly solve the problem as you mention below:

> My problem is how to repopulate the cache without waiting for a read to trigger it

As far as I know there is no standard way to do it. The reason for it, is that the expiry is not timer based.

(Shameless) hint: Since I think this is quite useful, I implemented this in [cache2k](http://cache2k.org). The feature is called background refresh, enabled by `CacheBuilder.backgroundRefresh(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

may be this code could help :

https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/issues/328